# How to keep affiliations of ieeeconf in one line

Tags: affiliation, ieeeconf, author

How can I decrease the distance between author blocks such that all of my three affiliations remain on one line and no break occurs?

Here is what I have now:

[image]

`MWE`:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

%%%%%%%%%%for conference header
\makeatletter
\let\old@ps@headings\ps@headings
%\let\old@ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle
\def\confheader#1{%
    % for all pages except the first
    \def\ps@headings{%
        \old@ps@headings%
        \def\@oddhead{\strut\hfill#1\hfill\strut}%
        \def\@evenhead{}%
    }%
    % for the first page
    \def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{%
        \old@ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle%
        \def\@oddhead{}%
        \def\@evenhead{}%
    }%
    \ps@headings%
}
\makeatother

\confheader{%
    \parbox{20cm}{nth International Conference on ...}
}
%%%%%%%%%%for conference header

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%for copyright notice
\def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{%
    \def\@oddfoot{\mycopyrightnotice}%
    \def\@evenfoot{}%
}
\def\mycopyrightnotice{%
    {\footnotesize  978-1-....-...-./../\$31.00 \textcopyright2017 IEEE\hfill}% <--- Change here
    \gdef\mycopyrightnotice{}% just in case
}
%%%%%%%%%%%

\def\thmheadbrackets#1#2#3{%
    \thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}%
    \thmnote{ {\the\thm@notefont[#3]}}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\algrule}[1][.2pt]{\par\vskip.5\baselineskip\hrule height #1\par\vskip.5\baselineskip}
\makeatother

%\linenumbers

\begin{document}
\title{The title}
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{X. Xxxxxxxxxxx}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Dept. of Electrical and Computer Engineering\\
University of EEEEEEE\\
CC, uuuuu iii GGG\\
Email: xxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx@aaa.zzzzzzzz.yy}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{C. C. C. Ccccccc}
\IEEEauthorblockA{cccccccc ccccccccccccccccccccccccc ccccccc\\
WWWWWW University of Technology\\
CCCCCC, WWWW\\
Email: a.sdgvbhgsdbdd@qqqqqq.uu.oo}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{A. Aaaaaaaa}
\IEEEauthorblockA{pppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp\\
    NNNNNNNNNNNN University\\
    YY, XXX\\
    Email: aaaaaaa.bbbbbbb@ttttt.ttt.ttt}
}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
...\end{abstract}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What you're asking for is not possible. Even reducing the spacing between the author blocks to `0pt`, there is still not enough space to fit all 3 in a single line. In your MWE, try adding `\renewcommand{\and}[1][\hspace{-0.317cm}]{\end{@IEEEauthorhalign}#1\begin{@IEEEauthorhalign}}% ` somewhere in your preamble and play around with the `\hspace`. Note that this space is negative (!!) and inadvertently means your author blocks must overlap. I can only think of enlarging the page dimensions, or reducing the font size,..

Comment: Just FYI, the default h. spacing set by the `\and` command is `\hfill`, so if it doesn't fit, it really doesn't fit.